# PHPUnit Mock of MongoCollection class creating a _PHP_Incomplete_Class object

Tags: mongodb, phpunit, php-mongodb, php-5.4

Today I came back to a project I have not touched for a while. It is a Zend Framework 2 project using MongoDB as its database.

I decided since it had been a while to update MongoDB to the latest version (2.4) from (2.0), and the driver to the latest (1.4.2?).

Now when running my PHPUnit tests I get errors due to a mocked **MongoCollection** class failing a "**is_a()**" test.

Instead of the new mocked class being an instance of **MongoCollection**, it turns out to be a **_PHP_Incomplete_Class** instance instead. I have been searching high and low and I cannot find anyone with the same issue. I can only assume something has changed to the *MongoDB* classes that *PHPUnit* doesn't like.

```
 $collection = $this->getMockBuilder('MongoCollection')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock();
```

When inspecting **$collection** I see:

```
_PHP_Incomplete_Class Object {
    _PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name => (string) Mock_MongoCollection_2798b1f7"
}
```

Does anyone know a way around this or do I need to bash out my own **MongoCollection** mock/test class to test with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a few days of doing other things I came back to this issue and have solved it.

I updated PHPUnit to the latest version (as of today, 1 August 2013) via PEAR and the issue has gone away.

The lesson: try updating everything and not just one component!